# Existence of PDF given a CDF with a countable number of jumps

Tags: probability-theory, continuity, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

This is in the context of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of a random variable and its corresponding probability density function (PDF).

Here, the important thing to note is that the CDF has a **countable** number of jumps and/or discontinuities.

For example, for a random variable $X$, it is given that

$F_{X}(x) = \begin{cases}0&,& x <-1\\ \dfrac{x+2}{4}&,& -1\leq x <1\\ 1&,& x\geq 1\end{cases}$

Here, we see that that $F_{X}$ has two jumps: at $x = -1$ and also at $x = 1$, since $F_{X}((-1)^-) = 0$ and $F_{X}(-1) = \frac{1}{4}$, and also $F_{X}(1^-) = \frac{3}{4}$ and $F_{X}(1) = 1$.

In situations like these (i.e., where the CDF has a countable number of jumps and/or discontinuities), does the PDF exist?

Also, if the PDF does exist, then how can we find the PDF of the random variable?

Comment: No.  Probability density function exists if and only if the cumulative density function is [absolutely continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity).

Comment: One jump is already enough for non-existence of PDF. A PDF is a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. So if $f$ is indeed a PDF then $\int_Afd\lambda=0$ for every Lebesgue null set $A$ (e.g. $A$ countable).

Comment: @user10354138 – Thank you for sharing the link. I went through it and a few of the related Wikipedia articles, but I am not sure I understood much. How can we define (or simply, state) "absolutely continuous" with respect to "continuous"?

I mean, for a "continuous" function defined as $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, say, for example, $f(x) = sin\space(x)$, what change must be done to the co-domain and/or domain to make it "absolutely continuous"? (Or, do we need to do something totally different to make it "absolutely continuous"?)